# How to apply pack200 using build file?

Tags: ant

How to apply pack200 using build file?
Please specify your answer where I am missing.

This is my code:

```
<target name="pack200">
   <apply executable="pack200" parallel="false" dest="${build.dir}">
      <arg value="--modification-time=latest"/>
      <arg value="--deflate-hint=true"/>
      <arg value="--segment-limit=-1"/>
      <targetfile/>
      <srcfile/>
      <fileset dir="${build.dir}" includes="*/.jar" />
      <mapper type="glob" from="D:/*" to="D:/*.pack.gz" />
   </apply>
</target>
```

Comment: edit your question correctly

Comment: Please use *relevant* tags. If unsure, check the description of the tag by simply hovering over it